# Installing PHP’s OCI8 Extension on Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: oci8

I don't have a oracle database installed in my system. But i want to connect to the remote system. Do i just need to install oci8 extension library or i need to install both instantclient and the oci8 extension?

Answer (score 0):

OCI8 requires 'Oracle Client libraries'.  Since you don't have these, you can install the free [Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html).  Install the Basic package for your OS. Use the correct 32- or 64-bit package that matches PHP's 32- or 64-bitness. If you are compiling OCI8 from source code, you'll also need the SDK package which has the necessary header files.

The details will depend on your OS and the version of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got this working with Canonical-Ubuntu-22.04-Minimal-2023.10.15-0.

These are the full instructions from a fresh Ubuntu-22.04-Minimal instance.

To begin with I got Apache and PHP installed:

```
sudo su
apt update
apt -y install apache2
systemctl restart apache2

iptables -I INPUT 6 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 6 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
netfilter-persistent save

apt -y install php libapache2-mod-php
php -v
systemctl restart apache2

echo '<?php
  phpinfo();
?>' > /var/www/html/info.php
```

Next it was [Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html)

```
mkdir /opt/oracle
cd /opt/oracle 

wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/2112000/instantclient-basiclite-linux.x64-21.12.0.0.0dbru.zip
wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/2112000/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.12.0.0.0dbru.zip
  
apt-get install unzip  
unzip instantclient-basiclite-linux.x64-21.12.0.0.0dbru.zip
unzip instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.12.0.0.0dbru.zip

sh -c "echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_12 > \
      /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf"
ldconfig

apt-get install php-pear
apt-get install -y php-dev
pecl install oci8-3.2.1

'instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_12'

cd /usr/lib/php/20210902/

echo "extension = oci8.so" >> /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
echo "extension = oci8.so" >> /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini

reboot
```

```
sudo su
apt-get install nano
nano /var/www/html/test.php
```

```php
<?php

if (function_exists('oci_connect')) {
    echo 'OCI8 is working!';
}
else {
    echo 'Not working!';
}

?>
```